# Is there a proverb in Portuguese equivalent to "Better lose the saddle than the horse."?

Tags: proverbios, ditados

It means that sometimes by sacrificing a little, one may avoid a much greater loss.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Mais vale perder os anéis do que os dedos

ou

> Vão-se os anéis e fiquem os dedos.

Comment: Mais vale uma pomba na mão que duas a voar. Pelo menos é muito usada aqui em Portugal

Answer (score 5):

There is saying in Portuguese, "Mais vale perder, que mais perder" that means "better to lose some than lose more/a lot".

Answer (score 0):

> Mais vale um pássaro na mão do que dois voando

Comment: "A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush." is not what I'm looking for.